# Box has a radius on the border but enclosed background color goes outside this

Tags: css

I'm on Chrome (38.0.2125.101) and have something that looks like this:

[image]

The css is:

```
  .if-container{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 12px;
    width: 400px;
  }

 .social-row{
     background-color: yellow;
     padding: 5px 20px 10px 10px;
 }
```

How would I make the css of the embedded element be clipped to the container (or fix it)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.social-row` `<div>` is overflowing outside of its parent container. Simply add this to your stylesheet:

```
 .if-container {
    overflow: hidden;
 }
```